# Trigger Workflow from User Event Script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm encountering an issue where a User Event script that loads, modifies, and then saves a Purchase Order (PO) is not triggering my workflows when the PO is saved by the User Event. My workflow is configured to run:

- After Record Submit,
- On View or Update and On Create
- In the User Event Script Context
- Released Status is Released

I've tried loading/saving the record in dynamic and standard modes in my UE script. The workflow is triggered when I make a manual change in the User Interface.

The help article [here](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4103800069.html) makes me think that this should work, unless it really only works on create, like the example has.

See my workflow context definition here:

[image]

See my code sample below:

```js
var po_id = context.newRecord.getValue('custrecord_po_conf_po');
var po_line_num = context.newRecord.getValue('custrecord_po_conf_line_num');
var confirmed_ship_date = context.newRecord.getValue('custrecord_po_conf_date');
var delay_notes = context.newRecord.getValue('custrecord_po_delay_notes');
var delay_reason = context.newRecord.getValue('custrecord_po_delay_reason');

var po_rec = record.load({ type: record.Type.PURCHASE_ORDER, id: po_id, isDynamic: true });
var line_num_id = po_rec.findSublistLineWithValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'line', value: po_line_num });
log.debug('line_num_id', line_num_id);
log.debug('po_line_num', po_line_num);
if (line_num_id >= 0) {
    // Update Line # with date
    po_rec.selectLine({ sublistId: 'item', line: line_num_id });
    po_rec.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'custcol_confirmed_ship_date', line: line_num_id, value: confirmed_ship_date });
    po_rec.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'custcol_po_delay_notes', line: line_num_id, value: delay_notes });
    po_rec.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'custcol_po_delay_reason', line: line_num_id, value: delay_reason });
    po_rec.commitLine({ sublistId: 'item' });
    try { po_rec.save(); }
    catch (e) { log.error('Unable to save PO - ' + e.name, e.message); return; }
    updated = true;
}
```

Comment: Check the release status of the workflow. It should be Released and not Testing or Not Initiating. Also the workflow should not be InActive but that isn't the default so usually is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks Brian! The workflow is set to Released, and I've updated the question to note that.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue trying to get a workflow to trigger transitions and actions after a User Event script updates a record of a different type that is related to the record in the workflow.

Since the issue is caused by inability in Netsuite to chain user events you can separate the events with a suitelet in between.

In other words to get the a user event to raise from the actions of a user event script, move the user event script logic to a suitelet then change the user event script to simply redirect to the suitelet.

Be sure to pass current record type and id from the user event script to the suitelet via the parameters array so it can redirect back to the record when it is complete giving the user a seamless experience.

Note that a suitlet is fine is the context is UI, otherwise you could launch a scheduled script with the same code, to which you pass the record id and type as a parameter.